# Is this right way to call api in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, api

I'm trying to make a server-side API connection.

So I installed and spring boot and made a Spring starter project.

And then I made an API request.

This is my Code.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    final String URL = "http://apis.data.go.kr/1360000/VilageFcstInfoService_2.0/getVilageFcst";
    String serviceKey = "0gr5uJKYx6b%2BlhmOt%2BDm%2BfbcxVdiG7U407njrJ3YSFLlrckPeysX5FZ3qoVA%3D%3D";
    String pageNo = "1";
    String numOfRows = "12";
    String dataType = "json";
    String base_date = "20211018";
    String base_Time = "2300";
    String nx = "55";
    String ny = "127";
    
        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(URL); /*URL*/
        urlBuilder.append("?" + URLEncoder.encode("serviceKey","UTF-8") + "="+serviceKey); /*Service Key*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("pageNo","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pageNo, "UTF-8")); /*페이지번호*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("numOfRows","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(numOfRows, "UTF-8")); /*한 페이지 결과 수*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("dataType","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(dataType, "UTF-8")); /*요청자료형식(XML/JSON) Default: XML*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("base_date","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(base_date, "UTF-8")); /*‘21년 6월 28일 발표*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("base_time","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(base_Time, "UTF-8")); /*06시 발표(정시단위) */
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("nx","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(nx, "UTF-8")); /*예보지점의 X 좌표값*/
        urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("ny","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ny, "UTF-8")); /*예보지점의 Y 좌표값*/
        
        
        URL url = new URL(urlBuilder.toString());
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        System.out.println("Response code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        BufferedReader rd;
        if(conn.getResponseCode() >= 200 && conn.getResponseCode() <= 300) {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        } else {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        
  }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to call API in spring boot.

I heard that to call API in spring boot I should use `WebClient`.
Is it right?? or Am I doing it the right way??

Comment: nope you are not doing it in a correct way. You need try web target.

Comment: This question is kind of opinionated, But `RestTemplate` should get you a much cleaner code

Comment: Does it work? If not, you are not doing it the right way. If it does, then you are. It's unclear exactly what your concern is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RestTemplate` to call any endpoint-

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity, String.class);
```

to create URI you can use `UriComponentsBuilder`-

```
UriComponentsBuilder url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://localhost:8080");
```

Comment: I heard that RestTemplate will be deprecated. So will be better to use WebClient??

Comment: Not really being deprecated, it will be there but will not be evolved from Spring 5. You can use WebClient too instead of RestTemplate.